# Custom Fields not showing on API return [Braintree]

Tags: braintree

I'm creating a customer like this using the [official Node SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_node) :

```
const createCustomer = (email, body) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    gateway.customer.create(
      {
        email,
        firstName: body.FirstName,
        lastName: body.LastName,
        paymentMethodNonce: body.Nonce,
        customFields: {
          countrycode: body.CountryCode
        }
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);

        return resolve(result.customer);
      }
    )
  );
```

> I have checked that body.CountryCode has a correct value.

When I enter in the Control Panel (Vault), I can see perfectly the country code like this:
[image]

But, when I try to get the customFields param from the API, is always an empty string:[image]

I have configured the custom field in **Store and Pass Back**

*(A Stored custom field will be stored with the transaction details and passed back.)*

Where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I will close ;) Thanks!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is a support product question

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. This question would best be answered through our support pipeline, as we'll need to gather some additional information from you. You can email support directly at support@braintreepayments.com Thanks!

Comment: @ThinkAboutIt It would be great if the resolution were posted here, if it might be relevant for other users.  I have a similar problem when doing transaction search.  A refunded transaction with no custom fields (done through the API) has an empty string for `custom_fields`.  This is using the Python library.